# Get the element in front of a specified pattern in tcl

Tags: pattern-matching, tcl, system-verilog

I am writing a script that will search a system Verilog testbench and pul out the modules and then search the modules hierarchy until it reaches the very bottom of the chain.

Is there any way to search for a pattern, and then take the element that comes just BEFORE the specified string? These files are all different except they will always have the element I need here...

```
//random code//
element_needed #(...)
```

or

```
//random code//
element_needed
    #(....
      ....)
```

I need the keyword that comes just before the `#(`. Ive been working with `regexp` but any ideas would be a huge help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# read the whole file into a variable
set fh [open "file"]
set contents [read $fh]
close $fh

# find the desired words
set elements [regexp -inline -all {\w+(?=\s*#\()} $contents]
```

That regular expression finds a "word" (letters, numbers, underscore) that is followed by optional whitespace (including newlines), a pound sign and an open parenthesis.

Comment: Thank you this works for me. Regular expressions is something im really trying to get better at.